# How can i calculate the number of unique rows in csv file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can i calculate the number of unique rows in .csv file using pandas in python. I tried the solutions but was only able to calculate the number of unique values in particular column only.

Comment: Depends on how you define 'unique'. Each row has an index, wich is unique. The question is: what do you want to know from the DataFrame? Then you can count the unique values from a specific column.

Comment: Please give some code to illustrate the specific question you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the shortest way would be this:

```
len(pd.read_csv('file.csv').drop_duplicates())
```

You just have to supply the csv filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
unique = yourData

rows = len(yourData)

unique.drop_duplicates()

uniqueRows = len(unique)
```

Check different options for drop_duplicates [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).